# display array of items from DB php/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am unsure how to display the `items` field. I want to display two tables of data; one that has all the items from a user and one with all the items to teh user. All I've been able to output is the `item_id's`(I pasted the html below). How to get all the item info from these ids, which is in the `item` table, and populate the HTML?

trans table

[image: TRANS TABLES]

`item` table

[image]

```
$from = 1;
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE from_id = :id");
$sql->bindValue(':id', $from);

$sql->execute();

while($row = $sql->fetch())
{
    $t =$row['items'];
    $u =$row['to_id'];
    $trans .= "<tr><th>Items</th><th>To</th><th>Status</th></tr><tr><td>$t</td>
            <td>$u</td></tr>";
}
```

HTML DISPLAY

[image]

Comment: The data is not normalised. Get it to 3NF and you'll have a much better and cleaner solution.

Comment: @Akshay I have no idea how to do that. HOw would that help in getting the data out. Any examples?

Comment: Here's a great resource - http://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/SDM04CD/page_01.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
<?php
    $from = 1;
   $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE from_id = :id");
   $sql->bindValue(':id', $from);

   $sql->execute();

  while($row = $sql->fetch())
    {
     $t =$row['items'];
     $u =$row['to_id'];
             $itemIDs = @explode(",", $t);
         $items = array();
            foreach($itemIDs as $ID){
            $sqlItem = $db->prepare("SELECT itemname FROM itemtable WHERE itemid = :itemid");
            $sqlItem->bindValue(':itemid', $ID);
            $sqlItem->execute();
            $itemname ='';
            while($rowItems = $sqlItem->fetch())
            {
                $itemname .=$rowItems['itemname'];
            }

            $items[$t] = $itemname;

     }   

        $trans .= "<tr><th>Items</th><th>To</th><th>Status</th></tr><tr><td>$items[$t]</td>  <td>$u</td></tr>";
   }
```

below is my code for  testing,

```
<?php

  $from = 1;
 $sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE from_id = '$from'");  
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
 {

     $t =$row['items'];
     $u =$row['to_id'];
     $itemIDs = @explode(",", $t);
     $itemname ='';
        foreach($itemIDs as $ID){
            $sqlItem = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT itemname FROM itemtable WHERE item_id = '$ID'");           

            while($rowItems = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlItem))
            {
                 $itemname .= $rowItems['itemname'].', ';
            }       


            $items[$u] = $itemname;

     }      
    $trans .= "<tr><th>Items</th><th>To</th><th>Status</th></tr><tr><td>$items[$u]</td>  <td>$u</td></tr>";
  } 

  echo "<table>".$trans."</table>";
?>
```

Comment: how come this will return item info from ur code?? it will return only string from `code`$row['items']`code`

Comment: @Ashish I don't know. It's supposed to return a string

Comment: No display. getting the `to_id` value though just not the `item_name`

Comment: Missed to add the, $sqlItem->execute();. Added that

Comment: ok its displaying only one item_name per `trans_id`. With `trans_id` of 1 it returns `girl upkn` which has an `item_id` of 23

Comment: I put this `$trans .= "<tr><th>Items...` into the `foreach` and all the item_names are coming out but so is each `to_id` associated with it

Comment: very nice. Thanks so much. Need to start researching more on MySQL

Answer (score 2):

**Note : change my queries with ur need**

in ur while loop

```
while($row = $sql->fetch())
{
$items_array = array();
$items_array = explode(",",$row["items"]);

    foreach($items_array as $key => $value)
    {                                       
        //modify ur query according to ur need
        $query3 = "SELECT  item_name
            FROM item_table 
            WHERE item_id =".$value." ";
        $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
        $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3);                                            
        $item_name .= $row3['subcategory_name'].", ";

    }
}
```

now ur array will contains item_id,
use foreach loop in ur while loop and get info of Item from item table with item_id from expolode function

Comment: I'll try it with PDO because that is deprecated code you're using

Comment: yes ofcourse u change queries..u will get item_id separate in to foreach loop

Comment: Don't I need another `while` loop for `query3`?

Comment: no..if items=21,22,23 then it will execute 3 times with foreachloop..u just try to echo $value in foreach loop u will come to know u got seaparate item_id

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it with PDO. mysql_query and mysql_fetch_assoc no longer work

Answer (score 1):

Within while you will have to fire new query that will get the information of items. 
For eg :

```
"SELECT * FROM item_info_table WHERE id IN (id1,id2, id3)"
```

It will return you the item information corresponding to the id's.

Comment: yes but my question is how to get the ids out of the db and into that query

Comment: Firstly you will have to fetch the ids by executing this query :
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE from_id = :id");

You will retrieve the ids something like this $row['items'] = '21,22,23'

Pass this whole data into 

"SELECT * FROM item_info_table WHERE id IN ($row['items'])"

Then it will return you all the data corresponding to these id's

Answer (score 0):

The data is not normalized. Get it to normalize and you'll have a much better and cleaner solution.

Comment: Did you just copy/paste this from Ashhay?